# Hosted App for Chrome that opens into fullscreen

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a "hosted app" for chrome.  I'm looking for a way to make it open into fullscreen. I have it now that it will open into fullscreen after the user hits a button.  What I'm looking for is a way to add a permission or something to the hosted app manifest that will allow me to programatically call `webkitRequestFullscreen` without